# How to find the latest binlog file name and position in slave mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

as the title show, I don't know how to achieve it in an effective way.

the command `show slave status` only shows the binlog file name and position corresponding to master instead of slave.

One way to do is to use command `show binary logs` to get the latest row's Log_name, and then use command `show binlog events in '{Log_name}'` to get the latest row's Pos. But that's isn't effective, because I only to want to get the latest row for above commands.

Are there any more effective ways to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you have to loop over the result set from `SHOW BINARY LOGS`. The names of the binary logs are stored in an index file, but not in INFORMATION_SCHEMA or PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA.

When executing `SHOW BINARY LOGS` MySQL reads and process the binary log index file in your data directory. It's usually named `hostname-bin.index`.

```
$> cat mozart-bin.index
.\mozart-bin.000001
.\mozart-bin.000002
.\mozart-bin.000003
...
.\mozart-bin.000113
```

MariaDB stores the latest binary log file and position in status variables `binlog_snapshot_file/position`, however this is not supported in MySQL.